# Blazor WASM Azure AD - Get & Use Refresh Tokens

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-msal, refresh-token

I am working on a Blazor WASM app and it is authenticating against Azure AD using the Msal authentication library from MS.

I specifically want to be able to retrieve the refresh token (which is coming back in the token response) and use the refresh token to retrieve a new access token.

Do you know how to do this?

Below is my configuration.

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount> 
(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
}).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount,CustomUserFactory>();
```

Getting an access token is easy, we inject the IAccessTokenProvider and call the method to retrieve the token result.

```
IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider;    
public AccessTokenService(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider)
{
    _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    var tokenResult = _tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
}
```

But how do I request the refresh token? I can see it in the token response but IAccessTokenProvider exposes no methods for retrieving it. Is there another service I need to use?

[image]

And after I retrieve it, how do I use the refresh token to request a new access token?

Comment: Msal should worry about refresh tokens for you.   I landed here because I thought I was having this issue, but in my case it turned out that I had a CSP policy which was blocking msal from opening an iframe.  I adjusted my policy to this (which allowed the expired token to be replaced by msal):  frame-src 'self' login.microsoftonline.com;

Comment: I agree with @Nathan - are you saying that the MSAL library should continue functioning silently with the cached refresh_token even if we are using LocalStorage/cookie for token mgmt? (i.e. have you actually got this working without endless Azure prompts?)

Comment: @Coruscate5 I was running into an issue with MSAL not making use of the refresh token, and assumed I had to do it myself. After lots of testing and reading docs/examples I found the sacred knowledge to getting MSAL to do this, which like you mentioned, involved setting MSAL CacheLocation to "localStorage". This setting has had an added benefit of reducing the constant "select a user to authenticate" AAD popup too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a access token and a refresh token, MSAL stores them in a token cache.

When you call `AcquireTokenSilent` MSAL will automatically use the refresh token if the access token is close to or has expired.

It is a process MSAL handles in the background for developers.

See:

1. [Acquire tokens silently from the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens#acquiring-tokens-silently-from-the-cache)
2. [SO: Get refresh token with Azure AD V2.0 (MSAL) and Asp .Net Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58482043/5503832)
3. [Refresh Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens)

Comment: I took a look, and from what I can tell, one cannot call AcquireTokenSilent in a Blazor WASM app. Do you possibly have this working in a Blazor App ?